# Firefox 3.6.13 messes up Mathjax

Tags: bug, status-completed, math-display

This problem was [first reported](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/slow-processing-different-look-to-math-processing-problem-with-fonts-is-it-me) on Math.SE. I'm bring this to your attention since Stats.SE also uses Mathjax.

Basically, the latest build of Firefox version 3.6.13 has a known issue of messing up Mathjax font(to the point where the font doesn't load). The devs of Mathjax are [aware of this](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues#issue/22), and are working on a fix.

Comment: Isn't that the better support of fonts was one of the features planned for this ff version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New OTF font files have been downloaded and applied to all installations where MathJax is used. If you are still having trouble clear your browser cache.